# How to allow regex match with one character wrong

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out if there's an easy way to have a particular regex give matches that are correct except for one character. (Working in PHP if that matters).

For example, for the pattern 'apples', I want to find not only occurrences of "apples" but also "appxes", "opples", "applis", etc.

Is there any good way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `levenshtein` function instead of regex. [Here are the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

On example `echo levenshtein("abcd","abce")` prints out: `1`.

**Edit:** Please also note that this function will compare strings of different lengths, so additional check could be needed. See @Vulcan's comment below.

Comment: It's noteworthy that `levenshtein("abcd", "abcde")` is also `1`. The function doesn't only account for a swapped character; it accounts for extra/missing characters as well.  If that extra functionality is undesirable, a simple filter could be added which only continues to `levenshtein` if the two strings are of equal length.

Comment: Great function to know about, thanks. The only issue here is that it doesn't work so well in context as far as I can tell? For example, consider a string "Here are some applis and oranges." I want to match "applis" for the "apples" pattern, not just determine that the Levenshtein distance between "applis" and the master pattern is one. That is, we need to find "applis" in context in the first place.

Comment: @G.Moore Then you'll have to test against every word, and allow levenshtein distances <= 1 to mean a match.

Comment: Suppose so. I wish there was a nice, clean way to do this! (I'm thinking something like a parameter in preg_match where you can specify number of chars than can not fit the pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex string:

```
[A-z]pples|A[A-z]ples|Ap[A-z]les|Appl[A-z]es|Appl[A-z]s|Apple[A-z]
```

Comment: should rather provide a function that could create that regex. not very useful for a dynamic solution...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think regex is the right tool for this. You could do something like this instead.

```
$temp = str_split ("apples");
$test = str_split ("appxes");
var_dump(array_diff($temp, $test));
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) { [3]=> string(1) "l" } // 1 mismatch
            ^ // position   ^ //letter at mismatch
```

Comment: In other words, checking that `count(array_diff(..)) == 1`?

Comment: This is a decent approach, although it boils down to a primitive version of levenshtein distance.

Comment: @Vulcan yeah. but `levenshtein` seems much better.

Answer (score 0):

you could spilt the string into X letters, and preg match X-1 from the desire preg match word.